# Spring Boot 2.1.9.RELEASE, Controller can't work well when controller extends base controller

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

```
public abstract class BaseController<E extends BaseEntity> {

    @GetMapping("/find")
    public ServerResponse find() {
        return ServerResponse.success();
    }

}
```

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/department")
public class DepartmentController extends BaseController<Department> {

    @RequestMapping("/find2")
    @ResponseBody
    public ServerResponse find2() {
        return ServerResponse.success();
    }
}
```

```
localhost:Temp nicq$ http GET :8010/api/department/find
HTTP/1.1 200
Content-Length: 0
Date: Sat, 12 Oct 2019 12:12:13 GMT
```

```
localhost:Temp nicq$ http GET :8010/api/department/find2
HTTP/1.1 200
Content-Length: 0
Date: Sat, 12 Oct 2019 12:12:17 GMT
```

I am expecting there are some json string in response body, but it is empty.

When i open the debug mode, the base find method is no executed.

I am implementing a generic controller. :<

Comment: what error do you see, seems something is missing because I am doing it successfully

Comment: there is no error message,  I got empty response body.

Comment: ok, does thing work without basecontroller

Comment: yes, it can work if I remove base controller codes from child

Comment: found the root cause , there is AOP Point Cut I set before, it has block the request and response. my mistake

Comment: glad you found out, I just verified with a POC and nothing seems wrong